# Установка готового скрипта на Framework Laravel 7-8 в другую папку

Tags: php, laravel, запрос, framework, установка

Здравствуйте дорогие формучане! Помогите разобраться как правильно установить готовый скрипт или CMS который был написан на **Framework Laravel** в другую папку например **/111/** (не в корень сайта),а именно в указанную папку. При загрузке файлов в site.ru/111/ должна начаться установка скаченного скрипта, место этого вот эта ошибка:

Warning: require(site.ru\111\public/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in site.ru\111\public\index.php on line 24

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'site.ru\111\public/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.') in site.ru\111\public\index.php on line 24

Подскажите пожалуйста как поправить путь чтобы скрипт работал в данной папке?

Comment: Не надо писать глупостей. Поиск в гугле - это **никакой не "сарказм"**. Это нормальная рекомендация, в 21 веке, когда от человека ожидается минимальное умение пользоваться интернетом.

Comment: Гуглить это можно так. Скопируйте сообщение об ошибке, удалив из него те части, которые уникальны для вашего случая.  Получится запрос типа "Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'vendor/autoload.php'". Затем изучите первые несколько ссылок выдачи гугла. Вы либо найдёте ответ на свой вопрос, либо поймёте как надо уточнить запрос.

Comment: @Ипатьев Я умею пользоваться интернетом, Google вообще написан на java, а не на PHP, и тем более этот сайт и предназначен для поиска ответа вроде этого.

Answer (score 0):

Правильнее было бы назвать приложение на Laravel не скриптом, а приложением. Приложение имеет определённую структуру. Есть точка вхда в приложение -- скрипт, который обрабатывает все запросы -- public/index.php. Как я понял, вам удалось настроить ваш сервер таким образом, чтобы этот скрипт запускался при обращении к site.ru/111.

index.php использует автозагрузчик composer'а. [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/) -- эта такая утилита, которая позволяет вам устанавливать библиотеки сторонних разработчиков (это важная часть инфраструктуры разработки на php, обязательно разберитесь что это такое). Ваш index.php сообщает вам, что не может найти файл автозагрузчика composer. Это значит, что вы ещё не устанавливали зависимости вашего приложения.

Чтобы установить зависимости вашего приложения, вам надо на сервере, в директории с приложением вызвать команду `composer install --no-dev`. Composer должен быть [установлен](https://getcomposer.org/download/) (например, просто скачайте phar-файл). На сервере это надо сделать, потому что composer обращает внимание на окружение (версию php, установленные расширения).

Когда composer установит все необходимые зависимости, он сгенерирует файл автозагрузчика autoload.php. После этого ваш index.php уже не будет ругаться на его отсутствие.

Comment: В приложений уже установлен **Composer** и все необходимо. Но почему-то вот такая ошибка.

Comment: @RedelReiz загляните в папку vendor, из которой подключается autoload.php. Есть такая папка и такой файл? Если нет, то зависимости не установлены.

Comment: Спасибо. Единственный человек который без пафоса и брехни всякой. Нашел в чем проблема. **Спасибо большое еще раз.**